# Some clarification on Hateoas + SpringBoot + Kotlin (structuring responses)

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-hateoas

So as I understand there are kind of two (or at least two) formats out there that Spring Hateoas supports : `collection+json` & `hal`

I'm trying to use the `HAL` format (I think) but I'm having trouble getting one of my elements to render correctly

#### Function 1: (Returns Single `Resource`)

```
@GetMapping("/test2/{array_index}")
fun test2(@PathVariable array_index: Int): ResponseEntity<Resource<SDDFService>> {

    val service = SDDFService(globals.advertisements[array_index])

    return ResponseEntity(Resource(service), HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

The `JSON` returned by this call is:

```
{
  "content": {
    "serviceID": "FMS",
    "peerID": "FlightSim_0977",
    "peerName": "FlightSim",
    "translator": "SDDFTranslator:AdvTranslator",
    "transporter": "SDDFTransporter:CMSVTransporter#trumpet.mitre.org@41375",
    "contentIterator": [
      {
        "comment": "",
        "units": "",
        "type": "STRING",
        "key": "fms",
        "nestedContentSet": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "peer_id": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8090/test/peer_id/FlightSim_0977"
    },
    "peer_name": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8090/test/peer_name/FlightSim"
    },
    "service_name": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8090/test/service/FMS"
    }
  }
}
```

I like this because our root is `content` and we have the HAL style `_links`

#### Version 2 - Multiple returns

My issue is when I start returning a collection things get a little funky:

```
@GetMapping("/test3/{array_index}")
fun test3(@PathVariable array_index: Int): ResponseEntity<Resources<SDDFService>> {

    val service1 = SDDFService(globals.advertisements[array_index])
    val service2 = SDDFService(globals.advertisements[array_index+1])

    return ResponseEntity(
            Resources(listOf(service1, service2)),
            HttpStatus.OK
    )
}
```

```

The return I get looks like:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "sDDFServiceList": [
      {
        "content": {
          "serviceID": "FMS",
          "peerID": "FlightSim_0977",
          "peerName": "FlightSim",
          "translator": "SDDFTranslator:AdvTranslator",
          "transporter": "SDDFTransporter:CMSVTransporter#trumpet.mitre.org@41375",
          "contentIterator": [
.etc
```

My question is - is there a way to change the name of `sDDFServiceList`.  I've tried a variety of annotations and nothing seems to change it (except changing the class name itself)

#### Class Def

```
@JsonRootName("ROOT")
@JsonTypeName("typeName")
data class SDDFService @JsonCreator
constructor(@JsonProperty("content")  val advertisement: SDDFAdvertisement) : ResourceSupport() {

init {
    add(linkTo(methodOn(TestController::class.java).peerID(advertisement.peerID.toString())).withRel("peer_id"))
    add(linkTo(methodOn(TestController::class.java).peerName(advertisement.peerName.toString())).withRel("peer_name"))
    add(linkTo(methodOn(TestController::class.java).getByServiceName(advertisement.serviceID)).withRel("service_name"))
}
}
```

I've gone through just about every stack post I can find and tried a ton of different things - but as it stands all I can come up with is changing my class name - which will still get the `List` appended onto the end of it.

Why I don't understand is why a single `Resource` gets a `content` field but a `resources` object seems to get both `_embedded` and `<className>List` fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding a relation annotation on the class itself? Like:

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.core.Relation;

@Relation(collectionRelation = "services")
public class SDDFService extends ResourceSupport {

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that class comes from an external library - i guess I could do a wrapper around it?

Comment: But I wrapped - my internal class - added this annotation and you have solved my issue! :) thanks